# Consulta comparando dos campos de dos registros distintos

Tags: db2

Necesito realizar una consulta en una tabla que compare el valor de un campo de la tabla con el valor del mismo campo de la tabla en otro registro.

Si la tabla es algo así:

```
| Contrato   | Oper  | Importe |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 00002158   | B234  | -10.00  |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 00002158   | B217  | 120.00  |
+------------+-------+---------+
| 00002158   | B173  | 100.00  |
+------------+-------+---------+
```

Necesitaría encontrar aquellos registros donde, para el mismo contrato, el importe de la operación `B217` es mayor que el importe de la operación `B173`. 
Debería devolverme los dos últimos registros.

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

No se si es esto lo que necesitas, pero una sencilla select

`select * from tabla where contrato like '00002158' and importe>(select top 1 t.Importe from tabla t  where t.Contrato=tabla.contrato and t.Oper like 'B173')`